# Increase session expire_date in Django

Tags: python, django, session, cookies

Inherited a Django project, trying to make some simple changes.  Right now my sessions are timing out in 30 minutes which I need to increase.

Reading [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/sessions/#using-database-backed-sessions), I first tried to increase the `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE` from 1800 (30 minutes) to  86400 (one day).  I also disabled `SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE` as it appears from the docs that this does not work with `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE`

However, the cookies that get set in my browser are still set for 30 minutes (I clear them manually before I login) and my `django_session` table `expire_date` column is always set to 30 minutes after I log in.

Is there a second place I need to change this or a place where I also need to alter the `expire_time` for the session table?

Python 2.7.3, Django 1.5.2

Comment: logout, and log back in. Does the session expiry change then ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is a `request.session.set_expiry()` in the relevant view? This method would be used to
override the global setting.